# Need help in plotting surface with Show[] and Plot3D[]

Tags: plotting

I have the following surface to plot $$(1-\frac{z^2}{4})^{16}=x^2+y^2$$

I decied to express $x$ as $x=x(y,z)$. And met the difficulty when combining 2 plots. Here is what I've done.[image]

As u see I get only half a picture. Could somebody tell me what I am doing wrong and how to combine this 2 plots?

Comment: Please post code not, screenshots of code. That said, add `PlotRange-> {-1,1}` as an option to `Show`. Does that fix it?

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `Plot3D[{-1, 1} yourSqrtFunction, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]`.

Comment: @march Thx, it helped. But I got some ripples on the edge between 2 plots. How to fix this?

Comment: @SamsonovD Increase the number of points used in the plot, e.g. adding `PlotPoints -> 100` to `Plot3D`. Play with the number of `PlotPoints` until you get a smooth edge.

Comment: @MarcoB thx, it also helped.

Comment: `ContourPlot3D[(1 - z^2/4)^16 - x^2 - y^2 == 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 
  1}, {z, -1, 1}]`

Comment: @Artes that's the best option, thank you very much

Comment: @Artes That would be the best way indeed. Would you post it as an answer for future reference?

Comment: @MarcoB I don't think it should be posted since I'm sure this is a duplicate (I guess there are at least a few such questions on this site). However if you like you may post this answer.

Comment: @MarcoB sorry for the duplicate, but still, all your comments were very helpful

Comment: @SamsonovD You shouldn't worry. There's nothing very wrong with duplicate questions: marking as duplicate is a way of weaving connections among questions on the site, so that people can get to the answer they seek from multiple entry points. I'm glad we could help!